# TransactionScope IsolationLevel not applied in Azure

Tags: sql, azure, transactionscope

On our database in Azure, we have a lot of deadlocks. We tried to change the isolation level of the TransactionScope class to read committed and seriazeble, but the deadlock graphs keep saying that the isolation level is read committed (2). We assume that it keeps using the read committed snapshot isolation level, which is the default one in SQL Azure.
Is there some other setting we need to set to have SQL Azure take the isolation level we want?

Code for transactionscope:

`Dim transOption As Transactions.TransactionOptions = New Transactions.TransactionOptions()
    transOption.IsolationLevel = Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
    Using scope As New Transactions.TransactionScope(Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOption)
        ...
        scope.Complete
End Using`

We have also tried to change Required to RequiresNew for the transaction scope option, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO    
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

More info:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1639.handling-transactions-in-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx